# Còmo hacer que lea el archivo txt por medio de estructuras c++

Tags: c++, string, archivo, estructuras

Tengo una tarea de crear un archivo txt que tiene que ser llenado por medio de una estructura, la cual contiene datos de personas.

Lo que ya he logrado es que al pedir datos de la estructura este cree un archivo txt con esos mismos datos por medio de la variable de la estructura `persona[5]`. El llenado de datos lo hago en la función `void escritura()`, la cual guarda los datos en las 5 posiciones del array de mi estructura.

No sé como hacer para que el programa lea mi archivo.

Creé una función llamada `void lectura()` para leer el archivo, pero no lo lee, a no ser que despues de haber llenado los datos, vaya al menú y ejecute la opcion 2, que es la de mostrar los registros.

Ahí si los muestra todos, pero si cierro el programa y quiero ver el archivo ya no muestra ninguno, a veces si muestra solo los datos de la primer persona, pero de las otras 4 no los muestra, es como si el contador que le puse al ciclo no avanzara y no recorriera el array. Perdonen si tiene errores, o si la sintaxis no es perfecta pero todavía estoy empezando.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

struct persona
{   
    int id;
    char nombre_apellido[70];
    char telefono[9];
    char correo[30];

}persona[5];
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    HANDLE hcon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD dwPos;
    dwPos.X = x;
    dwPos.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hcon, dwPos);
}
void bienvenida()
{
    gotoxy(42, 12.5);
    cout << "Bienvenid@ \n";
    Sleep(700);
    system("cls");

    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        gotoxy(42, 12.5);
        cout << "Cargando Sistema... ";
        cout << i << "%";
        Sleep(1);
        system("cls");
    }
    system("cls");
}
void despedida()
{
    system("cls");
    gotoxy(42, 12.5);
    cout << "Cerrando Programa";
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        cout << ".";
        Sleep(700);
    }

}
void escritura()
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "------ Ingresar Registros -------\n";

    ofstream archivo;
    archivo.open("persona.txt", ios::out);

    if (archivo.fail())
    {
        cout << "No se pudo abrir el archivo... \n";
    }
    else
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
        {
            fflush(stdin);
            cout << "Id: " << j << "\n";
            persona[j].id = j;
            cout << "Nombres y Apellidos: ";
            cin.getline(persona[j].nombre_apellido, 70, '\n');
            cout << "Teléfono: ";
            cin.getline(persona[j].telefono, 9, '\n');
            cout << "Correo: ";
            cin.getline(persona[j].correo, 30, '\n');
            archivo << persona[j].id << " " << persona[j].nombre_apellido << " " << persona[j].telefono << " " << persona[j].correo << "\n";

        }
        archivo.close();
    }
}
void lectura()
{
    int i = 0;
    ifstream archivo;
    archivo.open("persona.txt", ios::in);

    if (archivo.is_open())
    {
        cout << "--- Datos Personas Registradas---\n";
        while (!archivo.eof())
        {
            i++;
            if(i<6)
            {
                archivo >> persona[i].id >> persona[i].nombre_apellido >> persona[i].telefono >> persona[i].correo;
                cout << "Id: " << persona[i].id<<"\n";
                cout << "Nombre y Apellidos: " << persona[i].nombre_apellido << "\n";
                cout << "Teléfono: " << persona[i].telefono << "\n";
                cout << "E-mail: " << persona[i].correo << "\n\n";
            }
            else if(i==5)
            {
                archivo.close();
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "No se pudo abrir el archivo... \n";
    }
}
char valchar()
{
    char opcion_char;
    cout << "\nRegresar al menu (n/N) \n";
    cout << "Volver a realizar la operacion (s/S) \n";
    cout << "Elejir operacion---> ";
    cin >> opcion_char;
    while (opcion_char != 's' && opcion_char != 'S' && opcion_char != 'n' && opcion_char != 'N')
    {
        cout << "Ha ingresado una opcion invalida \n";
        Sleep(700);

        return false;
    }

    if (opcion_char == 's' || opcion_char == 'S')
    {

        return false;
    }
    else if (opcion_char == 'n' || opcion_char == 'N')
    {
        return true;
    }
}
int valint(int opcion, int rangoA, int rangoB)
{
    while (opcion<rangoA || opcion>rangoB)
    {
        cout << "Ha ingresado una opcion invalida \n";
        Sleep(700);

        return false;
    }

return true;
}

int main()
{
    fflush(stdin);
    int opcion;
    bool opcion_bool;

    system("Color A");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Spanish");

    //bienvenida();
    do
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "---- Menú ---- \n";
        cout << "1. Ingresar Registros \n";
        cout << "2. Mostrar Archivo \n";
        cout << "3. Salír \n";
        cout << "Elija una opción----> ";
        cin >> opcion;

        if (opcion >= 1 && opcion <= 2)
        {
            do
            {
                switch (opcion)
                {
                case 1:
                    escritura();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    lectura();
                    break;
                }
            } while (valchar() == false);
            opcion_bool = false;
        }
        else if (opcion == 3)
        {
            opcion_bool = true;
        }
    } while (valint(opcion, 1, 3) == false || opcion_bool == false);

    despedida();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Los arrays no empiezan en 1, siempre en cero, por lo que `for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)` es propenso a violación de segmento; si usas C++, ¿Por qué no usas `std::string`? Por último, hacer `fflush(stdin)` es comportamiento undefinido, sin mencionar que andas haciendo uso de ambos sistemas de I/O (El de C, y C++), lo cual puede reducir el rendimiento de forma drástica en tu aplicación.

Comment: Encerio? jaja perdon esque aun estoy empezando, con lo de I/O te refieres a las librerías? Si es por eso, es porque hay unos comandos que necesito que unas liberías no tienen, ahora lo de los arrays no me recordaba.

Comment: Eh!! Tranquilo, no hay nada de que disculparse, todoz venimos aquí a aprender ;), lo de IO, me refiero a `cout` y `fflush`. `std::string` está presente en `<cstring>` y creo que ya no se llama así la librería, saludos :D

Answer (score 3):

> Perdonen si tiene errores, o si la sintaxis no es perfecta pero todavía estoy empezando.

Razón de más para mostrarte los errores que vas cometiendo... es mejor verlos ahora que adquirir vicios dificiles de eliminar en el futuro.

Uno de los errores, ya que hablamos de ello, que estás cometiendo... bueno tu y el 99% de los que están aprendiendo es escribir esto:

```
fflush(stdin);
```

La función `fflush` está pensada para buffers de salida, no de entrada. Su función es vacíar el buffer volcando todo su contenido al dispositivo asociado a dicho buffer, que puede ser un fichero, una impresora, ...

De hecho la propia [documentación](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/) de `fflush` te avisa sobre los peligros de usarlo con buffers de entrada:

> In all other cases, the behavior depends on the specific library implementation. In some implementations, flushing a stream open for reading causes its input buffer to be cleared (but this is not portable expected behavior).

Es decir, que esa línea funcione para tu compilador actual no implica que te vaya a funcionar en otros entornos... si un programa empieza a hacer cosas raras puede ser por cosas como esta.

> No sé como hacer para que el programa lea mi archivo.

El problema es que estás asumiendo que la escritura y la lectura van a ser simétricas y eso es un error.

El contenido del fichero generado puede parecerse a este:

```
1 Mortadelo y Filemón 123 123@tia.es
2 Pepe Botella 456 chapuzas@tvo.es
3 Agente 007 007 007@mi5.gov
4 Superlopez 568 superlopez@ozu.es
5 yomismo 111 mi.correo@molamazo.es
```

El primer campo está claro... es un entero y es el id... a continuación es donde empiezan los problemas... el segundo campo es *nombre y apelllidos*... ¿Cómo sabemos donde acaba este campo?

- En el primer registro el campo abarca 3 palabras
- En el segundo registro son 2 palabras
- En el tercero son 2 palabras y encima la segunda es un número
- En el cuarto es únicamente una palabra

Luego:

- No puedes usar como delimitador el espacio ya que el número de espacios dentro del propio campo es variable
- No puedes leer hasta que te encuentres un número porque entonces en el tercer registro fallaría la lectura
- Teniendo en cuenta que en el campo *correo* se pueden poner también espacios, no sirve con leer toda la línea y empezar a procesarla *desde el final*

Así pues el formato que has elegido para guardar los datos no es válido o, al menos, no te sirve para recuperar la información de forma satisfactoria.

Una posible solución pasa por añadir, antes del nombre, un nuevo campo que indique la longitud del nombre y los apellidos. De esta forma sabrás exactamente dónde termina este campo:

```
void escritura()
{
  // ...
  archivo << persona[j].id << " "
          << strlen(persona[j].nombre_apellido) << " " // <<---
          << persona[j].nombre_apellido << " "
          << persona[j].telefono << " "
          << persona[j].correo << "\n";
}

void lectura()
{
  // ...
  int tamNombre;
  archivo >> persona[i].id >> tamNombre;
  archivo.get(persona[i].nombre_apellido,tamNombre);
  archivo >> persona[i].telefono;
  archivo.get(persona[i].correo,'\n');
}
```

Fíjate que la lectura del correo también la he modificado... en este caso va a leer todo lo que se encuentre hasta el salto de línea. Es el último campo así que no se espera que haya nada ahí que no pertenezca al correo.

Comment: +1 por el amor a F.Ibáñez y Jan.